# Adding Place Name Label to Google Map Markers in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have markers displayed on a Google Map and would like to add a UILabel of the name of each respective place.

Saw that the GMSMarker property title is specific to a marker's `infoWindow` and from the slim pickings of the available research, a custom icon might have to be made?

Are there any iOS examples of (easier) implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a custom marker you have to subclass `GMSMarker` and create it's `iconView` according to your needs.

From [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker#aa16a89bd5187e64e71c57c31c150a44d):

> - `(UIView*) iconView [read, write, assign]`
>
> Marker view to render. If left nil, falls back to the icon property
>   instead.

Example:

```
class CustomMarker: GMSMarker {

    var label: UILabel!

    init(labelText: String) {
        super.init()

        let iconView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 50, height:     80)))
        iconView.backgroundColor = .white

        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width:     iconView.bounds.width, height: 40)))
        label.text = labelText
        iconView.addSubview(label)

        self.iconView = iconView
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let marker = CustomMarker(labelText: "my_label")
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
marker.map = //your mapView object
```

Note that `iconView` is only used to create a markdown for your marker to be rendered. Your marker won't be intractable as a usual `UIView`, so adding any gestures or complex scrollable views to it won't take any effect.

Comment: This will change the pin (marker) position on the map.